# Como identificar algarismos numericos em numeros dentro de uma lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

preciso de uma ajuda. Estou preso em um exercício onde alem de várias orientações, pede para que eu remova todos os números dentro de uma lista que terminem com 7 (17, 27, 37, etc)

Como eu faria isso? (python)

Comment: o que você tentou fazer?

Comment: Tentou usar o operador % (resto da divisão)?

Comment: tentei usar outro for para percorrer cada algarismo de cada item, mas não consegui. É uma com  números de 1 a 100. Tentei usar a lógica de verificar se o segundo algarismo do número termina em '7' (como se fosse o indice de um string). Mas não deu kk.

(utilizei o % para remover os múltiplos de 7, uma das coisas que o exercício pede)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é utilizar a função built-in [`filter(função , iterável )`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) que cria um iterador a partir dos elementos de `iterável` para os quais a `função` filtro, passada no primeiro parâmetro, retorne `true`. O iterável pode ser uma sequência, um contêiner que suporta iteração ou um iterador.

Como filtro passe uma [expressão lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) que nada mais é uma função anonima:

```
lambda x: x % 10 != 7
```

Essa expressão lambda devolve a referência para uma função anonima contendo um único parâmetro,`x`, tal que se a unidade de `x` não for `7` retorna verdadeiro, caso contrário retorna false.

**Código:**
No caso criei uma lista hipotética chamada `lista` cujo os elementos são os números naturais de 0 até 99.
Depois apliquei o filtro, a cima descrito, de forma que seja feita apenas uma única iteração pelos elementos de `lista`.

```
#Cria uma lista com os naturais de 0 até 99 para teste.
lista = list(range(100))

#Filtra os elementos da lista cujo a unidade seja 7
resultado = list(filter(lambda x: x % 10 != 7, lista))

print(resultado)  #imprime o resultado
```

Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/EagerSourArchitects)

**Saída:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,   
 5, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 48, 
49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 70, 71, 
72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 
95, 96, 98, 99]
```

**Relacionado:**

- [Lista de Funções Built-in do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)
- [Typos de Dados Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)
- [Notação Big-O](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande-O)

**Pesquisas relacionadas aqui no site**

- [[python] filter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D%20filter)
- [[python]lambda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5Dlambda)
- [Big-o](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=big-o)

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar compreensão de listas para resolver o seu problema:

```
lista = list(range(100))
lista = [x for x in lista if x % 10 != 7]
```

Na segunda linha de código estamos dizendo que queremos todos os elementos da lista desde que o elemento dividido por 10 tenha resto diferente de 7.

Answer (score 1):

Tente:

```
for i in range((len(lista)-1),-1,-1):
  if (lista[i] % 10) == 7:
    del(lista[i])
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! obrigado!

tentei antes:

 for i in range(0, len(lista)):
    if(lista[i] % 10) == 7:
        del(lista[i])

Mas deu IndexError: list index out of range. Sabe me dizer o que porque? (aprendendo python ainda)

Comment: Começando a varredura pelo início da lista: `range(len(lista))` Acontece que conforme os números vão sendo excluídos o tamanho da lista diminui. Por isso em algum momento o range acabaria alcançando um número acima do de elementos da lista, o que causaria esse erro. Fazendo o contrário e varrendo a lista a partir de seu final: `range((len(lista)-1), 0, -1)`, o número vai diminuindo juntamente com o passo do iterador "-1".

Comment: Caso o primeiro elemento da lista seja `7` ou terminado em `7` ele não sera removido da lista com o laço acima. Uma solução seria passar `-1` como stop do `range`, ficaria assim: `for i in range(len((lista[i]-1), -1, -1).`

Comment: Obrigado, vou editar ali :)

Comment: Para listas pequenas não faz diferença, mas em operações com lista grades essa estratégia não é muito performática. Remover itens individualmente pode ser uma [operação custosa](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), compare a [complexidade de tempo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_de_tempo) entre apensar um item ao final da lista(`Append[1]`) e remover um item qualquer(`Delete Item`).